# Inline frame vs AJAX .

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am new to web development and creating a quiz website related to puzzles involving images using PHP/MySQL. A typical question is like given a series of related images , what would be the most fitting image next in series from the given 5 images in options.

Now for going to next question , I don't want whole page to refresh but only the part containing questions must change .
Since the question involves multiple images , will using AJAX result in slow loading of images or is it better i use inline frame to contain the questions .?

Comment: If it can be done without iframe - don't use iframe

Comment: It's up to you, I'd go with ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use AJAX to load the images themselves. You just need to update the URLs for the image files, and the browser will do the rest.

Use AJAX to update the question text.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a feature called upvoting :)

Comment: Sir I have less than 15 reputations , I can't upvote ... Thanx for your help :-)